# Nunit compile error in Visual Studio .Net

Tags: .net, nunit

Using Visual Studio .Net (2003) am trying to compile a legacy solution originally written in Visual Studio .Net (2003), which has a test project that used nunit (2.4.8), and I am getting an error on build:

Metadata file 'c:\Program Files\NUnit 2.4.8\bin\nunit.framework.dll' could not be opened -- 'Version 2.0 is not a compatible version.'

I have Nunit  2.4.8 downloaded at the path shown, and in the nunit.exe.config file I have the startup section uncommented to include the supportedRunTime versions etc. I have also checked that I have .Net 1.3075 installed on the machine.

Given that this project was built and tested on the same platform (even the same model computer, albeit a different physical machine), can anyone explain what else I need to do to get it to compile?

Comment: More information: this is the actual VS output: Performing Pre-Build Event...
        1 file(s) copied.
Preparing resources...
Updating references...
Performing main compilation...
fatal error CS0009: Metadata file 'c:\Program Files\NUnit 2.4.8\bin\nunit.framework.dll' could not be opened -- 'Version 2.0 is not a compatible version.'

Comment: As far as I can remember, VS 2003 does not support .NET 2.0. Are you using a .NET 1.1 version of NUnit? If not, I recommend that you download it here (2.4.8): http://sourceforge.net/projects/nunit/files/NUnit%20Version%202/NUnit-2.4.8-net-1.1.zip/download

Comment: I'm using Nunit 2.4.8, and it's the nunit.framework.dll from that directory that my test project references, and which is mentioned in the error message.

Comment: NUnit (any version number) comes in two flavors, one for .NET 2.0 and higher, and one for 1.1. Be sure to reference the 1.1 targeted version when you run NUnit in VS 2003.

Answer (score 0):

[Visual Studio .NET 2003](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_studio#Visual_Studio_.NET_2003) supports .NET Framework 1.1, and you will not be able to use a library that has been build for a later .NET version, i.e. 2.0 and higher.

[NUnit](http://nunit.com/) comes in two flavors, one that is targeting .NET 2.0 and higher, and one that is targeting .NET 1.0 and .NET 1.1.

To use *NUnit* together with Visual Studio 2003, download the .NET 1.1 version (named *NUnit-x.x.x-net-1.1.msi* or *.zip*) from a suitable download location, e.g. [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nunit/files/NUnit%20Version%202/V2.6.1/). Unpack/install the .NET 1.1 version to a suitable location. Then, in your unit test project, make sure you are referencing the 1.1 flavor of *NUNit* and nothing else.